# Passing $object to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Framework 5.5.25 and PHP 7.1.12.

I would like to pass a defined object to the view. I tried the following:

```
Route::get('/tasks', function getTask(TaskDataTable $dataTable) {
    return $dataTable->render('users.index');
});
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getUsers' (T_STRING), expecting '('"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in /home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/web.php:18
```

Any suggestions why?

Comment: Provide the code of where you have written `getUsers`

Comment: You have syntax error in your web.php file on line 18

Comment: @Виктор Yes I know, but I do not see why...

Comment: can you show this file ?

Comment: do you think **anonymous** functions/closures need names?  hint hint

Comment: @Виктор Basically I was trying to implement the datatable with buttons, but I do not get the buttons to show up in laravel 5.5. I am using the same code as described here: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-starter

Comment: Looks like a copy and paste error in the docs. I created a PR there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid PHP:

```
Route::get('/tasks', function getTask(TaskDataTable $dataTable) {
    return $dataTable->render('users.index');
});
```

You are attempting to define a function named `getTask` inside another statement.

I would imagine you want an anonymous function that can be passed around as a Closure:

```
Route::get('/tasks', function (TaskDataTable $dataTable) {
    ...
});
```

> "Anonymous functions, also known as closures, allow the creation of functions which have no specified name. They are most useful as the value of callback parameters, but they have many other uses."
>
> [PHP manual - anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
>
> "Class used to represent anonymous functions. ... Anonymous functions, implemented in PHP 5.3, yield objects of this type."
>
> [PHP manual - class Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Comment: the code you have provided above is not the exact lines causing your error, but seeing that, your error is because of making this mistake, shown here, in other places